# I can't build my android app successfully: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+

Tags: android

I have been trying to build my Android app in Android Studio, but it is not building. It shows an error.

This is the error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         24.2.1
         24.2.0
         24.1.1
         24.1.0
         24.0.0
         + 23 more
     Required by:
         HelloAndroid:app:unspecified
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 23.157 secs
Information:See complete output in console
Information:0 warnings
Information:1 error
```

Comment: I guess u not have SDK version

Answer (score 0):

Go to you SDK manager (**Tools** -> **Android** -> **SDK Manager**) and install **Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) - API Level 25**

Also under **SDK Tools** tab update **Android SDK Build-Tools**, **Android SDK Tools**, and **Android SDK Platform-Tools**.

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the app file explorer, **(where your Java classes and XML files are shown, usually on left** open the **app** gradle file file. Please post the contents of the file to this question. This is to see that your gradle file is properly configured as I had a similar problem and fixed it afterward. **Note that I am posting this answer because you have not marked this question as answered!**
I will then edit this question with a properly **(hopefully)** figured out answer.